# Is there any way one can increase the data limit of google-cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

Cloud functions are used for triggering a mechanism if incase some event happens, but the events captures the data of 10MB max if incase one wants to move the data across the components like GCS to BQ, So, is there any way one can increase the data limit.

Answer (score 2):

No, the limits are set inside the product and can't be modified.  You could always try to file a feature request, but I wouldn't expect the product to increase its limits unless you have a very common use case.

Cloud Functions is not really intended to be used for high volume data transfers, so you should probably find another way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: I read the documentation and found like there is no way to increase the quotas or limits for processing the data used by cloud function. As this functionality is just been introduced to be used as a light weight function , for triggering the event. Rather than for processing the data for which GCP is having several other components and one such is DataFlow